# i need to execute parallel exeution using airtest , how to do?

Tags: automation

1)i connected two devices in adb and i gave two device udid in .bat file but only one device is running

@echo off
C:
cd C:\New folder
start airtest run CasinoGame.air --device android://127.0.0.1:5037/NZTODMMNJBL7ZHL7
start airtest run CasinoGame.air --device android://127.0.0.1:5037/ce58c40c7ce5
exit
i want to run multiple device at a time in airtest